# Unable to reach Jenkins through local host on windos

Tags: jenkins, localhost

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPQYF.png)
 I completed the setup through jenkins.war then minimized the browser and later when I clicked "create new job" this happend. 
Help me out

Comment: Please give more information about your problem.

Comment: Is this port open? Check your firewall settings.

Comment: Open Task Manager > Services. Check that Jenkins service is still running. Try to restart it. Check [Jenkins logs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/#windows) for any errors.

Comment: The thing is each time I want to use Jenkins I have to install the war file over and over again and if I close the cmd used to install, Jenkins goes down

Answer (score 0):

Try to reboot your pc and restart jenkins server after reboot.

Comment: The thing is each time I want to use Jenkins I have to install the war file over and over again and if I close the cmd used to install, Jenkins goes down